# How to reply to "Good day, sir"?

Tags: conversation, greetings

How to reply to

> Good day, sir

in the beginning of the conversation as a greeting?

Comment: It depends on whether "Good day, sir" is said as a greeting, as a parting comment, or as an abrupt dismissal.

Comment: @TRomano I asked as a greeting

Comment: You could respond with "Good morning" or "Good afternoon".

Comment: Would be weird if I said "good day to you too, sir "

Comment: It would be anachronistic in many parts of the English-speaking world.

Comment: Can we say, "You too, sir"? [Another Thread on another site](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/887469-how-do-YOU-respond-to-quot-have-a-good-day-quot)

Comment: What @TRomano: The only contexts I can imagine anyone saying *Good day, sir!* today would be if the speaker is deliberately mimicking a starchy "Victorian" style offensive leave-taking / dismissal (effectively meaning *Go away! Get lost!)*.

Comment: I'd reply with ANY beginning-of-a-conversation greeting as well. (i.e., 'Hi', 'Hello', etc.) Why? It is the beginning of the conversation after all.

Comment: You could reply with "And to you, sir/ma'am" or "Good day to you too, sir/ma'am". In addition to the dismissive use pointed out, people might say "good day, sir/ma'am" in order to lighten the mood or be jocular. So, it's entirely appropriate to be jocular right back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a question of etiquette and personal style than language. It's polite to acknowledge the greeting somehow. A simple "Hello" is sufficient. If you do wish to engage in conversation, then add a question or a bit of small talk. Examples:

> Hello, how are you?
>
> Good morning. Lovely day, isn't it?
>
> Hi, Bob, how's the wife and kids?

Comment: The answer has run-on sentences and mismatching subjects and verbs. "Hello! How are you?" "Hi, Bob! How are the wife and kids?"

Comment: It's perfectly cromulent idiomatic American English. Answered 2 years, 7 months ago. Have a nice day.

Comment: Idiomatic would mean the construct is considered acceptable for formal writing. However, this construct is not. [LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/socal/glendale-news-press/opinion/tn-gnp-a-word-please-looking-at-a-commas-role-in-a-direct-address-20151106-story.html) This falls under colloquial misuse and shouldn't be prescribed, in the same way that the following sentence, while totally intelligible to a most native speakers, shouldn't be prescribed on a forum about English language: Cz its tots cray!"

Comment: I understood the question to be about conversational English, not formal writing.